# How do I know the cache-line settings of my Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: hardware, cache

I am working on a 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04 machine, and I am asked to provide the "cache-line setting" of my machine. I am wondering can I directly inquire this information from the OS? Or I need to dig into the BIOS or some other places..

Comment: That is a processor mechanism. I have never seen it being controlled by the OS. So if it is a user setting at all, it would be in the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

On x86 cache lines are 64 bytes.  The lstopo tool will show you the L1/L2/L3 cache sizes (including data and instruction cache sizes).